# counting numbers in corresponding range

Tags: excel, frequency-distribution

let  suppose that we have following  numbers

```
49  57  38  73  81
74  59  76  65  69
54  56  69  68  78
65  85  49  69  61
48  81  68  37  43
78  82  43  64  67
52  56  81  77  79
85  40  85  59  80
60  71  57  61  69
61  83  90  87  74
```

and let us suppose we have following  class intervals

```
Lower limit  upper limit
35              41
42              48
49              55
56              62
63              69
70              76
77              83
84              90
```

what i want  is to count  how many numbers  occurs between  given intervals , for instance between [35-41], in excel i have tried following range

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$E$10,"<="&J3)-COUNTIF($A$1:$E$10,"<"&I3)
```

where  j3 and  I3  are upper and low limit, i think this formula is correct,  for instance let us consider following numbers

```
1    2   3  4  5  6   7  8  9  10  11  12
```

we would like to know how many elements are in range of  7-12,   there are twelve  number  that are less or equal to  12,  and  6 number  that are less then 7, so difference between is 6 number, so we have

```
7 8 9 10 11 12
```

so  i think my formula is correct  right?

Comment: what is the question? If it's just whether your formula is correct, couldn't that more or less easily be checked "manually"? If you want to know how the formula can be improved, then this would be better put to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . If on the other hand you have a suspicion that something is wrong with your code, then please give an example where it doesn't work as expected!

Comment: if I3 is the lower limit, should that not be `COUNTIF($A$1:$E$10,">="&I3)`

Comment: @PaulDixon No, it is subtracted from count of numbers `<=J3`, the formula is OK, `COUNTIFS` might be slightly more clean solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data like:

[image]

In **I2** enter:

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:E$10,"<=" & H2)
```

and in **I3** enter:

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:E$10,"<=" & H3)-SUM($I$2:I2)
```

[image]

This takes advantage of the fact that your thresholds do not overlap and have no gaps.

Comment: This can also be achieved using `{=FREQUENCY($A$1:$E$10,$H$2:$H$9)}` as an array formula in formula array `I2:I9`.

Comment: @AxelRichter  **You are correct!**  In the general case, your approach is better...I posted my simple approach to show how to take advantage of the non-overlapping thresholds with no gaps.

Comment: Your example is good. Using `FREQUENCY` is not better in general. I just wanted to mention that there is a `FREQUENCY` function in Excel already.

Comment: i know  frequency  function(actually i am teaching excel to my students), what i am trying is to give them simple examples to understand

Comment: @datodatuashvili  It may be valuable to give several examples to your students....thanks for the feedback.